# Docker Networking not working as expected

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am using Docker version 18.03.1-ce on Ubuntu Linux 16.04 to run Docker containers. On this specific machine and in contrast to my installation on my notebook with Docker 17.12.1-ce on Ubuntu 18.04 I notice a difference in behavior. 
When I start the same docker-compose deployment that runs with no problems locally on docker v17 on the host with docker v18 I cannot access my exposed and forwarded ports.

The deployment consists of 2 containers that communicate on a backend network. One of the containers also exposes a web port (on 4000) which I want to be accessible from the outside. A rather common setup I would think.

On the v18 installation I need to explicitly run `docker network connect bridge <containername>` to be able to access my exposed port. This connects my container with the exposed port to the default bridge network and only then can I access port 4000.

The other difference I notice is that on the v17 installation I can ping ip adresses in the backend network, eg ping 172.20.0.2 works. On the v18 installation this does not work. I can only ping hosts on the bridge network.

After reading a lot of docs I am not quite sure anymore which is actually the desired behavior as isolation of backend networks is actually a feature.

On the other side, I have not found ways to automatically connect my container to the bridge network and to a backend network. What would be the docker-compose syntax to achieve this ?

The compose file looks like this:

```
version: '3'
services:
  mqttweb:
    restart: always
    container_name: mqttsock
    image: mqsocksrv
    depends_on:
    - rabbitmq
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
    - "4000:4000"
    - "4001:4001"
    networks:
    - backend
    volumes:
    - logs:/root/.pm2/logs/

  rabbitmq:
    restart: always
    container_name: rabbitmq
    image: mqttweb_rabbit
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.rabbitmq
    hostname: rabbitmq
    environment:
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=rabbit
    - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=secret
    networks:
    - backend
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  logs:
```

Comment: Does the host have ipvs installed and ip forwarding enabled?

Comment: I am not aware of ipvs, ip forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Can you post your compose file

Comment: I put it in the post..